# C++ fileIO line count

Tags: c++, file, input, newline, counter

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(filename); //open the input file

stringstream strStream;
strStream << inFile.rdbuf(); //read the file

string str = strStream.str(); //str holds the content of the file
```

I am using this code to read from a file. I need to get the number of lines at that file. Is there a way of doing that without reading the file second time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Get Total File Line Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140148/c-get-total-file-line-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the contents in a string, so just inspect that string:

```
size_t count = 0, i = 0, length = str.length();
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    if(str[i]=='\n') count++;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to do this:

```
auto no_of_lines = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::count` which is in `algorithm` library helps you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

long long lineCount { std::count(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        '\n') };

std::cout << "Lines: " << lineCount << std::endl;
```

Comment: Not totally correct. `std::count` returns `Iterator::difference_type`, which in this case is `std::char_traits<char>::off_type` and that type is implementation defined. My point is that you should use `auto` and not `long long` if you want to make sure the right return type is used.